# The value from database is not displaying correctly in the label in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

The value from the database is not displaying correctly in the label. If you logged in using the username and password the label will show your fullname,studentnumber,course,yearand section but the fullname in the username that i've logged in are not match. Please help me?

```
        conn.Open();
        string sql2 = "SELECT fullname,studentnumber,course,yearandsection FROM students WHERE studentnumber = @studentnumber";
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(sql2, conn);

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentnumber", log.txtUsername1.Text);
        MySqlDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();


        while(rd2.Read())
        {
            lblName.Text = rd2["fullname"].ToString();
            lblStudNo.Text = rd2["username"].ToString();
            lblCourse.Text = rd2["course"].ToString();
            lblYrSec.Text = rd2["yearandsection"].ToString();

        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail

Comment: What do you expect ? What do you get ? We need more details.

Comment: Seems to me you have an issue with the data in the table, or perhaps you are misunderstanding the meaning of "fullname" which sure doesn't sound like it is supposed to contain a username. There is no problem with this code.

Comment: Check if you have two or more identical student numbers. If you do (let's say two students with same number), result will be two rows and your loop will iterate thru both. But, since you'll showing data in labels, only the last student's data will be shown. So, maybe you're expecting data from first, and getting last students data. Also, you're using text from  `txtUsername1.Text` control. Are you sure there's right data in there?